# How to handle and perform actions fast on websocket data in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, sockets, websocket, filestream

I am connecting to third party data feed provider's server using websocket. 
For websocket connection my code is :

```
this.websocket = new WebSocket("wss://socket.polygon.io/stocks", sslProtocols: SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls);
```

So when connection become established we are receiving nearly 70,000 to 1,00,000 records on every minute. So after that we bifurcating those response and store it in it's individual files. Like if we receive data for AAPL then we store that data into AAPL's file. Same as for FB, MSFT, IBM, QQQ,and so on. We have total 10,000 files which we need to handle at a time and store live records according to it.

```
public static string tempFile = @"D:\TempFileForLiveMarket\tempFileStoreLiveSymbols.txt";
public static System.IO.StreamWriter w;
private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  using (w = System.IO.File.AppendText(tempFile))
  {
     Log(e.Message, w);
  }
  using (System.IO.StreamReader r = System.IO.File.OpenText(tempFile))
  {
     DumpLog(r);
  }
}

public static void Log(string responseMessage, System.IO.TextWriter w)
{
     w.WriteLine(responseMessage);
}

public static void DumpLog(System.IO.StreamReader r)
{
  string line;
  while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
     WriteRecord(line);
  }
}

public static void WriteRecord(string data)
{
   List<LiveData> ld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiveData>>(data);
   var filterData = ld.Where(x => symbolList.Contains(x.sym));
   List<string> fileLines = new List<string>();
   foreach (var item in filterData)
   {
      var fileName = @"D:\SymbolsData\"+item.sym+ "_day_Aggregate.txt";
      fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).AsParallel().Skip(1).ToList();
      if (fileLines.Count > 1)
      {
         var lastLine = fileLines.Last();
         if (!lastLine.Contains(item.sym))
         {
               fileLines.RemoveAt(fileLines.Count - 1);
         }
      }
      fileLines.Add(item.sym + "," + item.s + "," + item.p + "-----");
      System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, fileLines);
   }
}
```

So, when websocket connection established and perform actions with live market data with our 10,000 files then it's become slower and also websocket connection become closed after few minutes and passing message like below :

```
Websocket Error
Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
Connection Closed...
```

I am performing whole this process because in next phase I need to perform technical analysis on live price of each and every symbols. So how can I handle this situation ? How can I make process faster then this processing speed? and how can I stop for connection closed ?

**After Edit**

I replace stream writer and temp file with String Builder like follow,

```
public static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
public static System.IO.StringWriter sw;
private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
      sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
      sw.WriteLine(e.Message);
      Reader();
}

public static void Reader()
{
     System.IO.StringReader _sr = new System.IO.StringReader(sb.ToString());
     while (_sr.Peek() > -1)
     {
            WriteRecord(sb.ToString());
     }
     sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);
}

public static void WriteRecord(string data)
{
     List<LiveData> ld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LiveData>>(data);
     foreach (var item in filterData)
     {
           var fileName = @"D:\SymbolsData\"+item.sym+ "_day_Aggregate.txt";
           fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).AsParallel().Skip(1).ToList();
           fileLines.RemoveAt(fileLines.Count - 1);
           fileLines.Add(item.sym + "," + item.s + "," + item.p)
           System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, fileLines);
      }
}
```

Comment: Writing to files is going to be slow no matter what you do. Maybe buffer the messages and then write them later - this way you can avoid file io

Comment: @PatrickHollweck, Yes that is also possible that store live data into temp file and set timer for every 1 minute which will collect data from temp file on every 1 minute and then process on it. But if possible with live data then this would be better to work with live price. And in our option it will be process on 1 minute delay price data. So I recommending this option first.

Comment: It would be faster to save data into a database then a huge file.  A database like SQL Server is designed to handle real time data storage.  A file when opened takes up lots of memory.  When you append to a file it takes forever to open and move to end of file in windows.  As the file size gets larger the time to move to end get larger.

Comment: @jdweng, Yes that is better, But I am handling Day data, Minutes data, Quotes data, and Trade data for each symbols and each part handling nearly 25,000 records. So for each symbol there will be 1 lac records. And I will be have total 10,669 files. So may be this type very large data can be hard to handle on any db so I try with memory mapping files.

Comment: Memory mapping will never work.  Databases are designed to handle very large amounts of data.  It looks like you only have 250 million records.  If you put the data into a huge file how long is it going to take to read file?  Large memory mapping eventual lead to data ending up in very slow swap space on on a drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you *append* each message to the `tempFile`, but then you process the *entire* `tempFile`. This means you are constantly re-processing the *old* data *plus* the new record, so yes: it will gradually take longer and longer and longer until it takes so long that the other end gets bored of waiting, and cuts you off. My advice: don't do that.

There's also a *lot* of things you could do more efficiently in the actually processing of each record, but that is irrelevant compared to the overhead of constantly re-processing *everything*.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. if we use StringBuilder then can it affect on process instead of StreamWrite and tempfile?

Comment: @Ankit that... isn't the point; the point is that you're currently creating *and re-processing* an ever-increasingly-large file; now... yes, obviously if you don't touch the file system things will be *faster*, but presumably you *want* the data on the file system. The problem is that you keep *re-processing* everything. So... don't do that?

Comment: Our WriteRecord method is not able to write every response into the particular symbols file. we are receiving 80,000 records on every minute and we have 10,000 symbols file. So response is very fast and write all record in file is very slow.
So main purpose of tempfile is to if write record in symbol file becomes slower then we can not lost it. We can collect it from tempfile.
But if we can get very high speed  for write response in symbols file then we do not require tempfile and stringbuilder also.
So is there any way to make process very fast in WriteRecord method ?